# Configuring STONITH on non-shared disk cluster

Tags: high-availability, sles, pacemaker, fencing

I have configured a 2 node (VMs) cluster with SUSE High Availability Extension.

The cluster doesn't use shared disk. So Stonith is not really required. But the cluster keeps on asking for Stonith.

So what basic stonith can i create ??

Answer (score 2):

> So Stonith is not really required.

False. That type of cluster requires a fencing mechanism, whether or not it has shared storage. Only one host should get the cluster resources at any given time, and if the cluster is partitioned that gets very tricky.

> ### [Node Fencing/STONITH](https://documentation.suse.com/sle-ha/15-SP3/single-html/SLE-HA-administration/#sec-ha-requirements-hw)
>
> To avoid a “split brain” scenario, clusters need a node fencing
> mechanism. In a split brain scenario, cluster nodes are divided into
> two or more groups that do not know about each other (because of a
> hardware or software failure or because of a cut network connection).
> A fencing mechanism isolates the node in question (usually by
> resetting or powering off the node). This is also called STONITH
> (“Shoot the other node in the head”). A node fencing mechanism can be
> either a physical device (a power switch) or a mechanism like SBD
> (STONITH by disk) in combination with a watchdog. Using SBD requires
> shared storage.
>
> Unless SBD is used, each node in the High Availability cluster must
> have at least one STONITH device. We strongly recommend multiple
> STONITH devices per node.

Keep reading the manual for [node level fencing](https://documentation.suse.com/sle-ha/15-SP3/single-html/SLE-HA-administration/#sec-ha-fencing-nodes) options. Physically power off, such as with a UPS, PDU, or lights-out management interface.

Comment: I've read the manual and now understand that stonith is required, do back to my other questions. What's a basic stonith that I can configure on the VMs and how to configure that??  I've checked options that were mentioned on the manual, but the one's that I think would be best there aren't any "how to configure "for those options